# Host lookup failed when executing artisan on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-artisan

I keep getting this error when trying to execute artisan.

```
In UdpSocket.php line 47:

socket_sendto(): Host lookup failed [-10001]: Unknown host
```

The problem seems to be affecting `composer` as well.

I run Laravel 5.5 on a homestead virtual machine, everything was working as expected until this problem arrived in a very random way.

I really don't know where to start to debug this,

Thanks for the help!

Comment: From the command line, can you `ping google.com` or `ping 8.8.8.8`? The error doesn't say what host it's trying to access. Check the `__construct()` function of every Command class to make sure it's not trying to access a bad URL somewhere.

Comment: `ping google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8` are ok. The only Command class I have is the default Laravel class `Deploy`...